# ISNULL behaviour in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, isnull

As per my understanding IsNull Function checks the first value if its null or blank then it returns the next value.

```
SELECT ISNULL(1,getdate())
```

but the above statement is giving error. Can any one help to highlight the reason?

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: What is the desired result from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed, make the first value a char

```
SELECT ISNULL('1',getdate())
```

BTW, just be aware that ISNULL is not ANSI is proprietery and only accepts 2 parameters, COALESCE accepts a lot more

```
DECLARE @1 INT,@2 int, @3 INT, @4 int
SELECT @4 = 6

SELECT COALESCE(@1,@2,@3,@4)
```

This statement below is incorrect

> IsNull Function checks the first value if its null or blank then it returns the next value.

it doesn't care for blanks

run this

```
SELECT ISNULL('','A')    -- Blank is returned not A
SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'A')  -- A is returned because the first value is NULL
```

another difference between ISNULL and COALESCE is that ISNULL will return the same length as the first parameter

run this

```
DECLARE @c CHAR(3)

SELECT ISNULL(@c,'not available')  -- not
SELECT COALESCE(@c,'not available') --not available
```

Comment: Thanks for the Info,but does ISNULL checks the datatype of the second parameter as well even if it find the first value as not null

Comment: BTW: `coalesce(1,getdate())` does work as it casts the other way round according to precedence not according to 1st parameter.

Comment: Some details on the differences between coalesce and isnull: http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/isnull-vs-coalesce/

Comment: Thanks SQLMenace, Also Thanks Martin for highlighting the Precedence factor , Alun - Great link , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to replace an Integer with a Date.  Try this SELECT ISNULL(1,2) maybe instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to autocast doing this but I really would not recommend it. It's super unclear to someone else looking at this what it is trying to do:

```
SELECT case when not 1 is null then 1 else getdate() end
```